# Return pointer to array from function with array dimensions after function name

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return

I came across this odd function declaration in my code base that I would like help understanding:

```
struct MemberStruct (*GetMember ( 
    CONTAINER_STRUCT *Buffer 
    ))[DIM_1][DIM_2][DIM_3]
{
  return(&Buffer->MemberStructArray);
}
```

It behaves like a pseudo-accessor. It returns the address of the `MemberStruct` array within `CONTAINER_STRUCT`.

`CONTAINER_STRUCT` has this definition:

```
typedef struct ContainerStruct {
  // Other members
  struct MemberStruct        MemberStructArray[DIM_1][DIM_2][DIM_3];
  // Other members
} CONTAINER_STRUCT;
```

This function is called like this:

```
// declarations at the top of a function
struct MemberStruct (*MemberStructArray)[DIM_1][DIM_2][DIM_3];
CONTAINER_STRUCT Container;

// Other code, including the initialization of Container

MemberStructArray = GetMember(&Container);
```

I'd like to better understand the function signature, and haven't been able to find any examples of this construct online. My specific questions are:

1. How do the array dimensions *after* the name of the function work? How do they relate to the return type when the function name is between the return type and the dimensions?
2. Why is the `*` symbol inside the parenthesis with the function name? Since this is returning an address, shouldn't the reference operator be bound to the return type rather than the function name?

Comment: [The clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) is always useful to know. As is https://cdecl.org/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude cdecl.org chocked on this when I tried. But I'll review the sprial rule again. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking up the declaration: `GetMember` is a function:

```
GetMember()
```

That takes one parameter of type `CONTAINER_STRUCT *`:

```
GetMember(CONTAINER_STRUCT *)
```

And returns a pointer:

```
*GetMember(CONTAINER_STRUCT *)
```

To a 3D array:

```
(*GetMember(CONTAINER_STRUCT *))[DIM_1][DIM_2][DIM_3]
```

Of `struct MemberStruct`:

```
struct MemberStruct (*GetMember(CONTAINER_STRUCT *))[DIM_1][DIM_2][DIM_3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I suppose the answer to any followup questions will be "because that's the way C is". It's the "To a 3D array" part that throws me off. It doesn't make sense to me for the array dimensions to be outside the parenthesis and on the right-hand side of the function name. That looks like an array of function pointers to me.

Comment: @skrrgwasme: If `a[N]` is an array, then `*ap[N]` is an array of pointers and `(*pa)[N]` is a pointer to an array.  Replace `pa` with `f()`, and you get `(*f())[N]`, or a function returning a pointer to an array.   And yeah, this is how C declarator syntax works.  Function declarator syntax is similar - if `f()` is a function, then `*fp()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*pf)()` is a pointer to a function.  Replace `pf` with `a[N]`, and you have an array of pointers to functions - `(*a[N])()`.